# cannot rename because item does not exist

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Trying to search a folder for files not already ending in *.txt which have not been modified in 1 day and rename the extension to .txt

```
$app_files = get-childitem "C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files - TKT0087521\Test" -recurse -exclude *.txt | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
    foreach ( $file in $app_files ) {
        $newfile = $file.Name + ".txt"
        Rename-Item -Literalpath "C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files - TKT0087521\Test\$file" $newfile
    }
```

> Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at
>   'C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files -
>   TKT0087521\Test\C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files -
>   TKT0087521\Test\01-06-2019.log'  does not exist. At line:5 char:9
>   +         Rename-Item -Literalpath "C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename D ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
>   Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at
>   'C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files -
>   TKT0087521\Test\C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files -
>   TKT0087521\Test\01-07-2019.log'  does not exist. At line:5 char:9
>   +         Rename-Item -Literalpath "C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename D ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
>   Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at
>   'C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files -
>   TKT0087521\Test\C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files - 
>   TKT0087521\Test\08-05-2019.log.log' does not exist. At line:5 char:9
>   +         Rename-Item -Literalpath "C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename D ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: PLEASE fix your code formatting. i cannot tell what is code and what is error text ... or if there IS any code in that horrible mess. [*grin*]

Comment: The error happens because `"$file"`, `$file.ToString()` and `$file.FullName` are the same strings. Try  `… -Literalpath "C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files - TKT0087521\Test\$($file.Name)" …`

Comment: `-Literalpath $file.FullName`

Answer (score 0):

```
$RootFolder = 'C:\Users\adm.aross\Desktop\Rename DHL files - TKT0087521\Test'
$CheckDate = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-1)

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $RootFolder -Exclude @('*.txt') -Recurse:$true |
    Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $false } | # Check is file, not a directory
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTimeUtc -lt $CheckDate } | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTimeUtc -lt $CheckDate } |
    Where-Object { ( Test-Path -LiteralPath "$($_.FullName).txt" -PathType Any ) -ne $true } | # Check if there is no .txt file already
    ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.Name).txt" }
```

1. Check WriteTime and CreationTime. There can be situations when file
   is created AFTER written ( when file is copied from another source,
   WriteTime is copied, and CreationTime is not )
2. Check you can rename the file (the target name not exist )
3. Check it is a file